# Move JPanel in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, move

I'm looking to move a jpanel inside of a JFrame, and it won't seem to budge.  I can set it's location in the paint() method, but it won't update in repaint.  Please help!  Here is my code:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(playerImg, x, 50, null);
    this.setLocation(x, 50);
}

public void update() {
    this.repaint();
}


public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {
    if(key.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        x = x + 50;
        System.out.println("e");
        update();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) never set location in a paint method as that is asking for trouble. 2) You shouldn't even be overriding paint but rather `paintComponent` of a JPanel or JComponent. 3) Are you sure that you want to move a JPanel? It is more common to try to move a JLabel or an image. 4) Swing programs should not be calling the `update()` method. 5) for absolute positioning to work, the container must use a `null` layout, a dangerous non-layout to use.

Comment: 1) Why are you trying to set the position of a component? 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Answer (score 3):

*"I can set it's location in the paint() method"* - Don't, seriously, you should never modify the state of any component within any `paint` method, in fact, you've broken the paint chain by not calling `super.paint`, which is going to cause you no end of other problems.

Instead, set the parent containers layout manager to `null`, you will now find that the component disappears.  This is because the layout manager is responsible for setting the size and position of the component, which you will have to take over control of.

Instead of overriding `paint` you should be overriding `paintComponent` and calling `super.paintComponent`.  Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: I added the super.paintComponent(), and I set the layout of my JFrame to a FlowLayout(), however, the Image in my JPanel is invisible now, no matter if the layout is null or Flow.

Comment: That's because you `JPanel` is providing no size hints.  And make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent` from within `paintComponent` and not `paint`.  If you remove the layout manager, you become responsible for not only the position but the size of the component...